# Java: Y-Sort Algorithm | Sorting an Array of different object types

Tags: java, android

Im making a 2.5D game. To draw the elements in the right Order, I want to sort them by their Y value.

```
Object[] everyThingObjectArray = new Object[maptiles.length+buildingsArray.length+livingBeingsArray.length+rocksArray.length+projectileArray.length];
    for(int i=0;i<everyThingObjectArray.length;i++){
        //Sort objects
    }
```

How can I compare the Objects? I will probably need to downcast them from the Object class to do so. Do they each need to implement a Comparator?

Or is there another way to handle drawing order in an isometric game that i'm not aware of?
Thanks a lot for any answers!

Comment: It would probably be easier to create a super(mother) class instead of the java.util.Object. You could create x and y values in there, then make every object inherit that class; E.g. ParentObject, and could create a comparator there or do it 'manually', since every object inheriting will have x and y coordinates by default

Comment: Not just "easier" but **better**: you see, all the objects in that array share ONE property at least: they can be "drawn". And good OOP suggests that you create helpful abstractions (aka classes) to **express** such things. Like a base class (or maybe interface) `Drawable`. Seriously: Java is an OO language. Use OO concepts, or you will end up with a huge mess quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort can be used for sorting with an option to use a comparator in argument.
Or you can implement any standard sorting algorithm like merge.